# CSS Change in multiple locations on hover (jquery solution needed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working in wordpress, trying to figure out how to change the css color of a side nav element when a remote image is hovered.

I would have done this easily with CSS and just assign the CSS hover class for each item, but since this is a CMS, the navigation and the image gallery will change dynamically.

So, I'm looking for a JQuery of how to accomplish this.  Any suggestions?

Here's an example of the html:

```
<div class="imgGallery">
 <img class="page-item-54" src="/image1.jpg">
 <img class="page-item-66" src="/image2.jpg">
<div>
```

When someone hovers over the specific image above, it changes the css of the image below:

```
<ul class="pageNav">
 <li class="page-item-54">Sub Gallery 1</li>
 <li class="page-item-66">Sub Gallery 2</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!
Troy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

You may want to look at changing `<ul class="pageNav">` to `<ul id="pageNav">` (unless you know for sure you will never duplicate this class).

Edit: updated to allow for multiple classes in the `img` tag.

```
$(function() {
    var $pageNav = $('.pageNav');
    // hook up hover function to all images under the imgGallery class
    $('.imgGallery').find('img').hover(function() {
        // find "page-item-" class
        var pageItemClassName = this.className.replace(/.*(page-item-\d+).*/, "$1");
        // toggle hovered class on matching item under unordered list
        $pageNav.find('.' + pageItemClassName).toggleClass('hovered');
    });
});​
```

You can then make a hovered css class which will apply when hovered. For example:

```
.pageNav .hovered {
    background-color: #009900;
}
```

Comment: Nope... didn't work.
Should I be putting this in the head of the document?  That shouldn't matter... right?

Also, would it affect it if there were two classes assigned to each item?  So, for example, "page_item page-item-54" is the two classes.

Comment: Correct, putting it in the head should not matter. However, having an extra class in there does break the implementation I proposed. I updated the code to work with multiple classes in the `img` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function to hook up handlers for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events of the images (which jQuery will happily simulate on browsers that don't support them):

```
$(".imgGallery img").hover(
    function() {
        // Code for when the hover starts, the (raw) hovered `img`
        // element is `this`, from which we can get the class name
        // to feed into a selector for finding the relevant `li`
        $(".pageNav ." + this.className).css(/* your change here */);
    },
    function() {
        // Code for when the hover ends, the (raw) unhovered `img` 
        // element is `this`
        $(".pageNav ." + this.className).css(/* your change here */);
    }
);
```

Here's a live example with [just one `pageNav`](http://jsfiddle.net/KgXnL/), and [a revision with multiple `pageNavs`](http://jsfiddle.net/KgXnL/1/) just to show that it is updating multiple locations simultaneously.

`mouseenter` and `mouseleave` (IE innovations that still aren't supported natively by many browsers, but which jQuery provides if missing) are a lot less difficult to work with for this sort of thing than `mouseover` and `mouseout`, since `mouseover` and `mouseout` bubble. (In your case, it may not matter much, as you're using `img`s; if you were using elements that could have child elements, though, it would make a big difference.)

Comment: Probably not a worry in this case, but worth noting that calling `$(".pageNav " + this.className)` for each event, could cause performance issues. It would be better to cache `$('.pageNav')` above the `hover` definition as something like `var pageNav = $('.pageNav');` and then use it with `find` as `pageNav.find('.'+this.className).css(/*your change here*/);`

Comment: @Nate: The overhead of the event and the user's action will *far* outweigh the overhead of the lookup. And you're assuming that the structure under `pageNav` is static, which it may or may not be... (I assumed the structure under `imgGallery` was.)

Comment: @TJ, I agree, the overhead of the lookup is not a big deal in this case. However, correct me if I am wrong, but caching the initial lookup of `$('.pageNav')` and using `find` to locate the `li` children, should indeed work correctly if the structure under `pageNav` changes.

Comment: @Nate: *"...caching the initial lookup...and using find...should indeed work correctly if the structure under pageNav changes..."* Yes quite so, for some reason I thought you meant caching each `li`.

Comment: @Troy: I was missing two dots (one in each function), it had `$(".pageNav " + this.className).css(...` but it should have been `$(".pageNav ." + this.className).css(...`. Fixed now, with live example.

Answer (score 0):

You can FAKE a CSS HOVER with the code bellow

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var images = $(".imgGallery img");

    $.each(images, function(i, item) {      
        $(item).mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css({
                "background-image": "url('alternate_image.png')",
                "background-repeat": "no-repeat"
            });
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $(this).css({
                "background-image": "url('original_image.png')"
            });

        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this jQuery script, I add and remove a second class class "over" that you can style accordingly.

```
$(function () {

    $('div.imgGallery img').hover(
        function () {
            $('ul.pageNav li[class=' + $(this).attr('class') + ']').addClass('over');
        },
        function () {
            $('ul.pageNav li[class=' + $(this).attr('class') + ' over]').removeClass('over');
        });

});
```